# Paypal API, Curl request, get list of orders of customers

Tags: api, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Need a **Curl** command who can get all **transaction_id** between **two dates**.

Exemple :

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2021-12-01T00:00:00-0700&end_date=2021-12-30T23:59:59-0700&transaction_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer %token%"
```

But without the **transaction_id**.

Comment: Remove `&transaction_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX` from your API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove &transaction_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX from your API call

[Preston PHX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069605/preston-phx)